# $wpdb SELECT query is returning the COUNT?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I'm pretty new to using WordPress and am having an issue with getting my expected result. I am trying to pull from the WordPress database so I am using $wpdb. The following is what I have:

```
global $wpdb;
echo $wpdb->query("SELECT * FROM wp_users");
```

Rather than it echoing all of the users, it returns with the number of users in the table. If I add "WHERE id = *some number*" it echoes that ID number.

What is going wrong and how do I get it to select all from that table?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The function returns an integer corresponding to the number of rows
>   affected/selected. If there is a MySQL error, the function will return
>   FALSE. (Note: since both 0 and FALSE can be returned, make sure you
>   use the correct comparison operator: equality == vs. identicality ===)

You can use `get_results` to fetch all records

```
 global $wpdb;
 $users=$wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_users" );
print_r( $users);
```

Manual [**Class_Reference wpdb**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb)